# Как реализовать проверку: используется ли файл другими программами?

Tags: c#, .net

#### Суть проблемы

Имеется папка с файлами (~500 файлов), которые необходимо удалять. При удалении файлов возможен такой вариант, когда некоторые из них открыты в других программах либо запущены (если файл исполняемый). Не могу найти способ проверять перед удалением файла, есть ли у меня к нему полный доступ.

#### Пробовал:

1. Открыть файл в потоке в монопольном режиме.

```
try
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(_pathToCheckAccess,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None));
}
catch (Exception) { canAccess = false; }
```

Не срабатывает, когда файл заблокирован другим процессом

2. Использовать сторонние библиотеки от непроверенных поставщиков (`Meziantou.Framework.Win32`).

Есть работающая реализация  метода проверки, но использовать библиотеку непроверенного поставщика нет возможности.

Comment: Попытаться удалить. Не удаляется — значит, заблокирован :)

Comment: С другой стороны, предварительная проверка - бесполезное занятие, так как файл внезапно кто-то может открыть в период между проверкой и фактическим удалением. То есть даже если проверка прошла успешно, это не значит, что удаление пройдет успешно, и наоборот, если проверка провалилась, то удаление тоже провалится. Отсюда сама проверка становится полностью бессмысленной.

Comment: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30114833/5045688), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497959/5045688) - перемещаем файлы во временную папку. Если все переместились, то удаляем её (файлы в ней гарантированно ничем не держатся). Если хоть один файл не переместился, возвращаем всё обратно.